# AngularJS - Access JSON object associated to a model

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that returns JSON, assume this is the response:

```
{
    "model": 48870,
    "id": 20
}
```

I can do this:

```
$scope.response = Service.get();
```

And it will assign the JSON response to `$scope.response`. The issue here is I cannot directly access `model` or `id` via `$scope.response.model` or `$scope.response.id`, respectively. My workaround for this situation is to define a function in the service's success callback and fetch `model` or `id` from `data`. But this is not very practical considering `$scope.response` contains the entire JSON object and should in theory (and the sake of clean code) let me access its children.

Two questions here:

1. Is it a limitation of AngularJS representation of models?
2. How can I point to children (even grandchildren) without having to define a success callback for each call?

Comment: 1. Nope, there is no such limitation in AngularJS. 2. Depends on how you are using this model: html-template data-binding OR controller code. In case of latter, you'll definately have to make sure that `$scope.response.model` is loaded before using it (e.g., success callback), otherwise you'll be getting a ReferenceError.

Comment: What does your Service.get() look like? If you are using $http.get or something similar, this is probably an issue related to that function returning a Promise and not the actual JSON. This can be compounded by the fact that promises are "recognized by the templating engine in angular, which means that in templates you can treat promises attached to a scope as if they were the resulting values." [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q)

Comment: One of you should provide his comment as an answer so I can accept it. Both are correct and valid to me.

Answer (score 1):

Once the asynchronous HTTP call returns, it is safe to access response's properties directly.

[See this short example](http://plnkr.co/edit/itXVSJ9FBC9LmdnnEbO4?p=preview)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $resource) {
  $scope.data = $resource('data.json').get(function() {
    $scope.loaded = true;
    //now it's safe to access $scope.data's properties:
    $scope.data.foo = $scope.data.id + ':' + $scope.data.model;
  });
});
```

UI bindings will work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is described here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05